# Prepared Statement SQL Exception "No Input Parameters"

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement, derby

so I'm trying to retrieve data from a DB. Maybe I have looked at it too much but I can't find the problem.

Connection is fine, Statement is fine (works with static data), and data from the `Item` object is correct.

It's telling me there are no input parameters for the statement. The exception is being thrown in the `getSelectPrepareStatement()` method. The code is:

```
 public Result[] getItemsFromInput(Item item) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement statement;
    ArrayList<Result> results = new ArrayList<Result>();
    String query =  "SELECT Code1, Name, A.Code2 " +
                    "FROM ItemTable A " +
                    "INNER JOIN CategoryTable B " +
                    "ON A.CatCode = B.CatCode" +
                    "AND B.ID LIKE '?'";
    statement = getSelectPrepareStatement(query, item.getTail().getId()+"%");

    ...

    rs = queryForResultSet(statement);

    while(rs.next()) {
        results.add(new Result(
                rs.getString("ItemName"),
                rs.getInt("ItemCode"),
                rs.getString("ClassCode")));
    }

    return results.toArray(new Result[results.size()]);
}
```

Retrieving the PreparedStatement with set Values here:

```
private PreparedStatement getSelectPrepareStatement(String SQL, String data) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement pStmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
    pStmt.setString(1, data);

    return pStmt;
}
```

The eexception is being thrown on the call to `pStmt.setString(1, data);` although I set the statement to have a paramenter.

The error is:

```
    java.sql.SQLException: No input parameters.
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedResultSet.noStateChangeException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.setString(Unknown Source)
        at connection.Communicator.getSelectPrepareStatement(Communicator.java:306)
        at connection.Communicator.getItemsFromInput(Communicator.java:56)
        at frame.PromotionsDialog$1.propertyChange(PromotionsDialog.java:126)
        at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeSupport.java:335)
        at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:328)
        at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:263)
        at java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:303)
        at java.awt.Component.firePropertyChange(Component.java:8402)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.firePropertyChange(JComponent.java:4494)
        at frame.DataPanel$1.actionPerformed(DataPanel.java:130)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No input parameters.
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
        ... 51 more
    Caused by: ERROR 07009: No input parameters.
        at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericParameterValueSet.checkPosition(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericParameterValueSet.getParameterForSet(Unknown Source)
        ... 47 more
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the problem, in your SQL.

```
AND B.ID LIKE '?'
```

That's not adding a parameter - that's specifying a value of `?`, because it's in quotes. Basically, you're saying you want to find a row where `B.ID` is a single question mark.

You want:

```
AND B.ID LIKE ?
```

That way you're genuinely specifying a parameter.

Answer (score 4):

No need of single quotes for `?`

Try

```
String query =  "SELECT Code1, Name, A.Code2 " +
                    "FROM ItemTable A " +
                    "INNER JOIN CategoryTable B " +
                    "ON A.CatCode = B.CatCode" +
                    "AND B.ID LIKE ?%";
    statement = getSelectPrepareStatement(query, item.getTail().getId()+"");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the single quotes from around the bind parameter.  That's what PreparedStatement does for you.

```
String query =  "SELECT Code1, Name, A.Code2 " +
                "FROM ItemTable A " +
                "INNER JOIN CategoryTable B " +
                "ON A.CatCode = B.CatCode" +
                "AND B.ID LIKE ?";
```